# Color Coherence Vector in C#

Tags: c#, image, histogram

A friend and I are about to embark on creating a machine that performs some image comparison for sorting.  I know about histogram comparison and am generally confident that a small grid of histograms per image precalculated and stored in columns in a database table will generally give us pretty good matches on the first pass because we are matching like things.

The second comparison we want to perform is to use a [color coherence vector](http://tinyurl.com/4lo8nl) (CCV) of images which passed the histogram match test from our subject image to the candidate images.  I know that this sort of comparison is more precise.

My friend is confident that he can develop CCV in C# using the [C# wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Intel_OpenCV.aspx) to [OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/).  I am pretty sure he can too.  However I would like to know:

1. Has anyone already done this in C# and released the source code?  Or a C# wrapper?
2. Are we barking up the wrong tree?  (Should we just use CCV and forgo histogram comparisons at the database level?  Or is CCV too much?)

Answer (score 1):

The OpenCV site mentions compatibility with VB, so I wouldn't be surprised if it exposes a COM interface.  If so, just add a reference to it and let Visual Studio build the PIA (the wrapper) for you.

Unfortunately, I don't know the details of the image processing algorithms you mention, so I can't offer advice on your second question.

Comment: There is a C# wrapper which works pretty well, we've been using it with some success thus far.  Its just the CCV algorithm - if someone had already done it (OpenCV does not) I'd like to focus on the other parts of our problem for which no pre-existing solution exists.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think using only color coherence vector will achieve a good result in your application. I tried and it works very well. (This link provides a step by step implementation to [Color Coherence Vector](http://tarekmamdouh.hubpages.com/hub/Image-Retrieval-Color-Coherence-Vector) maybe you find it use

Also I found a matlab implementation which you can have a look at ([github link](https://github.com/TarekVito/ColorCoherenceVector))